# Creating lists from a list of strings without list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have a list m:

`m = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange']`

and I want output as follows:

`['Apple'], ['Lemon'], ['Orange']`

How can this be done without using list comprehension and for cycles?

In my approach I dont understand what variables to use. Any ideas?

```
def lists(m):    
    count=0`
    while count < len(m):            
        len(m)
        count += 1
        
    return #separated lists?

print(lists(m))
```

Comment: Are you wanting the problem solved without using list comprehension with for-loops or without using either list comprehension or for-loops?

Comment: (and are you fine with generator comprehensions?)

Comment: @l3viathan I doubt it, the OP seems to be going for a traditional `while` loop approach

Comment: When having such an oddly specific request as "no list comprehensions", it would be best if you could explain why exactly you are requesting that, so that the answer can account for whatever your specific reasoning is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked to avoid List Comprehension, you could try something like this: (BTW, `while` is just kind of `for` loop!)

```py
m = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange']

from typing import List

def split_list(lst: List[str]):
    
    res = []
    
    for item  in lst:
        res.append([item])

    return res


print(split_list(m))
```

Comment: It's a little strange that you create a `count` variable that you don't use. It's also a little weird to use `enumerate` if you don't plan on using the index. Why not `for item  in lst:`? On the other hand the OP was asking not to use `for` loops.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My bad - left from the OP 's code. Correct it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a traditional `while` loop approach. Details of how it works are in the comments.

```
m = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange']

def list_to_lists(lst):
    i = 0

    # this will be the result list, containing lists of strings
    res = []

    while i < len(lst):

        # [lst[i]] creates a new list containing the i'th element of lst
        # res.append will append this to the result list
        res.append([lst[i]])

        i += 1

    # return the result list
    return res

lists = list_to_lists(m)
print(lists)
```

Its been an incredibly long time since I've actually written a `while` loop. Do note that `for` loops are often neater for this sort of thing - see @daniel-hao's example.

Answer (score 0):

No list comprehension, presumably no "for cycles" (might depend on what you mean), and results in a `tuple` as requested.

```
>>> *map(lambda s: [s], m),
(['Apple'], ['Lemon'], ['Orange'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use recursion and parameter unpacking

```
def makeLists(first,*rest): 
    return [[first]] + (makeLists(*rest) if rest else [])

m = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange']

print(makeLists(*m))

# [['Apple'], ['Lemon'], ['Orange']]
```

You can also make it without parameter unpacking:

```
def makeLists(strings): 
    return ([strings[:1]] + makeLists(strings[1:])) if strings else []

m = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange']

print(makeLists(m))

# [['Apple'], ['Lemon'], ['Orange']]
```